# Voltage regualtor with 5v output @ 2.5 amps

Tags: battery-charging

I did some research online and could not find an answer to this. I have a 6v @ 12Amps(I think its 12amps) battery pack with 4 Super heavy duty d-cell panasonic batteries(1.5v each). I want to use it as a power source but I need to step it down to 5v output. I would like to do this with a voltage regulator but the ones Ive research only give 5v @1.5 amps, when I will be pulling 2.5Amps? Any ideas as what I could do or maybe a possible link to a regulator that can do this?

FYI don't worry as to what I will use the battery pack for or why I want to step it down, since that will just make this thread more complicated/more questions.

Comment: Note that a battery cannot be "12 amps", though it's very close. Batteries are usually rated in Amp-Hours (the number of hours you can draw an amp from the battery).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sounds like you need a switching converter.

These are very efficient voltage regulators that use the charging and discharging of an inductor and a capacitor to regulate voltage.

You could make one yourself, but you'd probably need a custom PCB for it, and I think it would be a better route to just buy one.

2a at amazon: https://www.amazon.ca/VIKINS-Adjustable-Regulator-Converter-Voltmeter/dp/B01CG9QHSG/ref=sr_1_sc_1?ie=UTF8&qid=1460824393&sr=8-1-spell&keywords=swiching+regulator

And a whole host of 3a switchers at ebay, if you don't mind the wait: http://www.ebay.com/sch/i.html?_odkw=switching+regulator&_osacat=0&_from=R40&_trksid=p2045573.m570.l1313.TR0.TRC0.H0.Xswitching+regulator+3a.TRS0&_nkw=switching+regulator+3a&_sacat=0

Basically, just search around for a "3A switching regulator".

One more thing: Since you're drawing from a battery, your input voltage probably won't be 6v most of the time, and it might go under 5v that you want to regulate to. What you need then is called a "Buck-Boost switching" converter. This takes any voltage within a range (say, 2-15v), and brings it either up or down to your target voltage.

Comment: Would buck converters be ideal for high torque servos that pull that 2.5amps current? Cause they fit the ratings I need, even though the maximum says 3 amps, would 2.5amps wear the converter down?

Comment: @cloudhalo Because switching converters are really efficient, you can get really huge current ratings on some: if you're worried about a 3A rating, you can get 5A versions:http://www.ebay.com/itm/DC-Buck-Converter-DC5-32V-to-0-30-0V-5A-30W-Adjustable-Voltage-Regulator-Adapter-/391417539619?hash=item5b224dac23:g:b1EAAOSwu1VW4jI4

Comment: May I please get a link to a Buck boosting switch that I can use. So my setup will look like this: connect the Buck boost switch to the input of the battery pack. Set the boost to 5v, then connect the switching regulator to the output of the buck boost(set it to 5v@2.5A), and finally connect the output of the switching regulator to where ever I need that specific 5v @2.5 amp rating correct?

Comment: I just need a link to get the right one for my setup(buck boost switch), cause its the first time I am doing this an I dont wanna look myself and buy the wrong thing which will waste money. Can you please post a link? And in my previous comment, is that how you would set up the the buck boost switch and switching converter to the battery pack?

Comment: @cloudhalo: you've got the setup/sequence wrong, methinks.  The buck-boost converter **is** what will be changing the battery pack voltage to the 5 volts your servos need, so you'll connect the battery pack **output** to the buck-boost converter **input**, then adjust the buck-boost converter **output** to 5 volts and use that 5 volts to power your servos.

Comment: Oh, so if i use a buck booster, then I don't need a switching regulator, correct? May I have a link to a buck booster I can use?

Comment: @cloudhalo A buck boost reg *is* a switching regulator. Here's a 5a buck-boost: http://www.ebay.com/itm/5-30V-to-0-8-28V-DC-Boost-Buck-Converter-5A-Constant-Current-Volt-Regulator-/301057850532?hash=item4618723ca4:g:jAIAAOSwZd1VbGTU

Comment: I just have one last question. If i set the current controller to 2.5 amps initially and the servos pull that for about 1 second as their stall current, then when the servos fully operate they pull 1 amp instead, will keeping the buck-boost initially at 2.5amps cause an issue?

Comment: @cloudhalo I think that's fine; The current controller drops the voltage so that the current stays the same.